# android python errno 10053

Tags: android, python, winsock

I am trying to learn creating the android application using python. I am going through the tutorials.

when I am running the command :

```
adb forward tcp:9999 tcp:4321
set AP_PORT=9999
```

and then running the code,

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
droid.makeToast("Hello from my computer!")
```

It gives me error as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    droid.makeToast("Hello from my computer!")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\android.py", line 58, in rpc_call
    return self._rpc(name, *args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\android.py", line 47, in _rpc
    response = self.client.readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host     machine
```

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: I can't tell you a fix, but the error number is something from WinSock. If you as a searchengine for "winsock error 10053", you should find a few things, the official docs are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx. Maybe it's just firewall settings of your system or something in between?